# Почему не выводит данные массива после get запроса

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, get

Я начинаю изучать js параллельно с vue. У меня есть сервер и отправляю ему get запрос, и хочу полученный ответ передать в глобальную переменную, чтобы в будущем использовать в других участках кода. Но почему то, когда я хочу вывести полученный результат, высвечивается пустой массив. Не могу понять почему, буду рад любой помощи.

```
messageApi.get().then(result =>
  result.json().then(data =>
      // console.log(data) -> выводит json
      message= JSON.stringify(data)
  )
);
console.log(message) -> пустой массив
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас данные приходят асинхронно с сервера и поэтому console.log(message) отрабатывает раньше чем приходят данные и выводятся пустой массив. Попробуйте сохранять данные с сервера в `data vue` и запрос вызывать в методе жизненного цикла `mounted vue`, когда vue приложение загрузится данные уже должны будут доступны(тут зависит от вашего сервака и времени ответа)

```
messageApi.get()
  .then(result =>
    result.json();
  ).then(data =>
      this.message = JSON.stringify(data)
  )
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Мне кажется, я Вас не совсем понял. Вот как я реализовал   
let message= {};  Vue.component({ data: messageJson, mounted() { this.$nextTick(function () { messageApi.get().then(result => result.json().then(data =>  this.message = JSON.stringify(data) ) ) }) } })